# Speed up a loop in R to eliminate part of a string in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, performance, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following huge dataframe:

```
> dim(cons)
[1] 14279806        5
> head(cons)
     Gene.ID        Gene.Symbol     Transcript.ID           miRNA context...score
1 ENSG00000188846.9       RPL14 ENST00000416518.1  hsa-miR-373-3p          -0.042
2 ENSG00000188846.9       RPL14 ENST00000416518.1 hsa-miR-520a-3p          -0.109
3 ENSG00000188846.9       RPL14 ENST00000416518.1    hsa-miR-520b          -0.085
4 ENSG00000188846.9       RPL14 ENST00000416518.1 hsa-miR-520c-3p          -0.085
5 ENSG00000188846.9       RPL14 ENST00000416518.1 hsa-miR-520d-3p          -0.109
```

What I have to do is to remove the number fter the "." in the columns Gene.ID and Transcript.ID, in both cases I have always 15 characters before the "." .
To do that I used this code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cons)){
  cons$Transcript.ID[i]<-substr(cons$Transcript.ID[i],1,15)
  cons$Gene.ID[i]<-substr(cons$Gene.ID[i],1,15)
}
```

Which is really time consuming (after 20 min it was under the 1% of the total).
I want to ask you: there is a way to avoid the for loop and speed up as much as possible the code?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substr` is vectorized, you can do just:

```
cons$Transcript.ID<-substr(cons$Transcript.ID,1,15)
cons$Gene.ID<-substr(cons$Gene.ID,1,15)
```

**EDIT:**

I see that you have duplicates, if your columns are already `factors` you could go faster by doing :

```
levels(cons$Transcript.ID) <-substr(levels(cons$Transcript.ID),1,15)
levels(cons$Gene.ID)       <-substr(levels(cons$Gene.ID),1,15)
```

If they're not factors you could convert them first, but it seems from @Benjamen's comment below that you may not gain time overall because of the conversion time.

```
cons$Transcript.ID <- factor(cons$Transcript.ID) 
cons$Gene.ID       <- factor(cons$Gene.ID)
```

Comment: On my system, I'm actually finding that using `substr` alone is faster than converting to a factor and then `substr`ing the levels.  But most of that is the conversion.  If they are already factors, then working on the levels is much faster.

Comment: I used the first solution and the runtime was great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Below is example for one million rows. Time in seconds

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(ID1 = paste0("MGH45328914",sample(c(1001:9999),1000000,replace = T),".2"),
                ID2 = paste0("NJK4123914",sample(c(1001:9999),1000000,replace = T),".6"),stringsAsFactors = F)
system.time(df <- df %>% mutate(ID1 = strsplit(ID1, ".",fixed = T)[[1]][1],ID2 = strsplit(ID2, ".",fixed = T)[[1]][1]))

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.22    0.00    0.22
```

Below example for 10 Million rows. Time in seconds

```
df = data.frame(ID1 = paste0("MGH45328914",sample(c(1001:9999),10000000,replace = T),".2"),
                ID2 = paste0("NJK4123914",sample(c(1001:9999),10000000,replace = T),".6"),stringsAsFactors = F)
system.time(df <- df %>% mutate(ID1 = strsplit(ID1, ".",fixed = T)[[1]][1],ID2 = strsplit(ID2, ".",fixed = T,)[[1]][1]))

# user  system elapsed 
# 9.42    0.15    9.61
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow for different string lengths, you can also use `sub` to take only what's before the ".":

```
cons$Transcript.ID <- sub( "\\..*", "", cons$Transcript.ID )
cons$Gene.ID <- sub( "\\..*", "", cons$Gene.ID )
```

Another option, just out of interest, is to specify a range of possible string lengths before the `"."`. This, for example, will accept any length between 10 and 20 before the period, returning only that part.

```
sub( "^(.{10,20})\\..*", "\\1", code$Transcript.ID )
```

Comment: I think matching `"\\.[0-9]+$"` might be a little robust.  `"\\..*"` will remove everything after the first `.` (perhaps acceptable in this case, admittedly)

Comment: That will only be more robust if we can verify that all characters after the `"."` are numeric. Probably the case here, but if a letter or other symbol appears after the `"."` it will fail.